# Tipo dos dados da configuração do nginx

Tags: nginx

Existe algum nome especifico do formato dos dados usado pelo nginx? 
Por exemplo:

```
upstream app1_upstream {
    server app1:80;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app1_upstream;
    }
}
```

Esse arquivo parece muito com um tipo `JSON`, mais obviamente não é.

Comment: Na realidade esse tipo de arquivo de configuração é chamado de vhost e não passa de um código interpretado pelo nginx. A estrutura de montagem desse arquivo pertence apenas ao nginx é um codigo emulado por dentro de um interpretador nativo. Nunca ouvi dizer que tivesse um nome especifico.

Comment: Pretendia montar algo que crie esse tipo de arquivo para utilizar como proxy reverso em servidores com docker, e queria evitar de ter que ficar concatenando milhões de string, imaginei que se esse tipo de formato fosse um padrão teria algo já pronto para manipula-lo

Comment: Não poderia utilizar json? A sintaxe é bem perto realmente de um json com expressão regular

Comment: Então, eu queria montar o arquivo de configuração do nginx usando python por exemplo, com informações obtidas do sdk do Docker, sabe me dizer se o nginx aceita configuração em json comun?

Comment: Nesses anos todos que mexo com servidores nunca ouvi  falar que aceitasse já olhou a documentação do nginx? Talvez você possa montar um interpretador.